# loop a math formula until two values are equal

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to work on a complicated math equation and part of it involves looping values until they are a specific difference apart.

Here is my attempt at this:

```java
public void EccentricAnomaly(double M) {
    double E = M + e;
    if (e > 0.06) {
        E0 = E;
        double anglesInRadianE = Math.toRadians(E0);
        double E1 = E0 - (E0 - e * Math.sin(angleInRadiansE) - M / (1 - e * Math.cos(angleINRadianE)));
        if (E1-E0 !=0.001) {
            E1 = E0;
            E1 = E0 - (E0 - e * Math.sin(angleInRadiansE) - M / (1 - e * Math.cos(angleINRadianE)));
        }
        v = Math.cos(E1) - e;
        x = Math.sqrt(e);
    } else {
        v = Math.cos(E) - e;
    }
```

The issue is that if `e` from a previous calculation is greater than `0.06`, `E1` is calculated but if the difference between that and `E0` is greater than `0.001` the formula used to calculated `E1` is done again, this time `E1` becomes `E0` and a new `E1` is calculated. This should repeat until the difference between `E1` and `E0` is `0.001`.

As you can see I'm confused how to program this, so any help would be appreciated. I think, this is the right path but this current code seems to just be repeating the same values.
As requested here is the original code:

Here is the math formula I'm trying to code:

First, compute the eccentric anomaly, E, from M, the mean anomaly, and e, the eccentricity. As a first approximation, do ( E and M are in radians):
    E = M + e * sin(M) * ( 1.0 + e * cos(M) )
If e, the eccentricity, is less than about 0.05-0.06, this approximation is sufficiently accurate. If the eccentricity is larger, set E0=E and then use this iteration formula (E and M in radians):
    E1 = E0 - ( E0 - e * sin(E0) - M ) / ( 1 - e * cos(E0) )
For each new iteration, replace E0 with E1. Iterate until E0 and E1 are sufficiently close together (about 0.001 degrees).

Comment: What is small e? I don't see it initialized with any value or passed into your method. If you're trying to use Eulers number that's not it. What happens when you run the program?

Comment: Please at least quote the original formula, and define your variables properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't compare for exact equality when you are using `double` type variables. You should forget about that word in floating point context. Two floating point numbers can be really close to equal but not equal. You should use a small epsilon value to compare with their absoulte difference, when it is smaller you can say that the numbers are close enough so that you can say that they are considered to be equal for **your** use-case. For example you can use such construct:

```
if(Math.abs(E1 - E0) < EPS){
   //you can assume they are equal
}
```

where `EPS = 0.001` in your case for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost directly translate your description to Java code: As long as `E1` and `E0` are farther apart than `0.001`, recalculate `E1`:

```
while(Math.abs(E1 - E0) > 0.001) {
    E0 = E1;
    E1 = E0 -( E0 - e* Math.sin(angleInRadiansE)-M / (1 - e * Math.cos(angleINRadianE));
}
```